# Use of Perfekt and Präteritum in the same sentence

Tags: perfect-tense, preterite

Other answers on related topics don’t seem to answer my question. I am considering the following German sentence which is from the recitation of a diary entry. I am quite sure that I have heard correctly:

> Im Tal haben wir in einem Restaurant ordentlich zu Mittag gegessen und bestellten zum Nachtisch eine große Portion Kaiserschmarren.

It seems that *haben…gegessen* is in Perfekt while *bestellten* is in Präteritum. Is it acceptable to mix Perfekt and Präteritum in this situation? I would have thought that *haben* could be inferred to be conjugated with both *gegessen* and *bestellt* such that both instances are in Perfekt, as in:

> Im Tal haben wir in einem Restaurant ordentlich zu Mittag gegessen und **bestellt** zum Nachtisch eine große Portion Kaiserschmarren.

Comment: It's not part of the question, but I'm pretty sure the "bestellt" would go at the end of the clause: "... und zum Nachtisch eine große Portion Kaiserschmarren bestellt."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite common in spoken language to mix Perfekt and Präteritum like that. Written language is a bit more strict but even in a newspaper article I would not flinch when reading something like that.

Answer (score 2):

What one would expect in basic German is that the perfect tense is used at both places, "Im Tal aßen wir in einem Restaurant ordentlich zu Mittag und bestellten...". Now I'd guess that in the commonplace fluidly spoken language the tense that needs a change in the vokal of the kernel (i.e. essen -> aßen) is avoided and replaced by the perfect ("essen -> gegessen"). On the other hand, a sentence like "there was no reason..." would translate as "es gab keinen Grund ..." rather than "es hat keinen Grund gegeben...", just for the sake of the shorter expression. It seems this is some kind of economy of speaking...